# Is it possible to alter a php file using XPath?

Tags: xpath

I"m unsure about this.  Would having PHP ( or I guess any template language like Django's or Mako or whatever ) inside an html file prevent me from making changes to it with XPath?

I'm very new to XPath.  I would think that you could not, but as I said, I'm unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Xpath` is a query language. You use it to query XML content, not change it.

You can use `Xpath` in conjunction with other technologies (XSLT is the first one that comes to mind) in order to query you XML and then use the results of these queries to transform your XML.

Answer (score 0):

**XPath doesn't change the XML document.**

**Use XSLT or a any other XPath-hosting language** that can produce a new XML document.